# Происхождение орфоэпических норм

Tags: орфоэпия

Откуда берутся орфоэпические нормы? С потолка? То есть, одному вздумалось написать в словаре, что произносится так и так, через некоторое время другой даёт совершенно другую норму.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Они устанавливаются исходя из распространённости того или иного произношения и общих тенденций в языке. Безусловно некоторые аспекты орфоэпических норм носят во многом волюнтаристский характер, например; какое произношение в русском языке считать нормой, слова, соответствующие новым тенденциям, но резко отрицаемые большОй частью общества, предпочитающей классическое произношение (*звОнит, ложить, кофе среднего рода* и др.), но в целом научная база у орфоэпических норм имеется.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!!!

Comment: Хотелось бы в это верить, но я почему-то встречаю на каждом шагу представителей маленькой части общества, к сожалению. А эта большая часть почему-то от меня прячется, видимо. :))) Например, был в Крыму летом в велопоходе и не помню, чтобы хоть раз (!) услышал за месяц, чтоб кто-то сказал "звонИт". :(

Comment: Артем, этот вариант настолько распространен, что, возможно, уже в ближайшем будущем попадет в словарь.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Дело в том, что определяющие норму ориентируются в первую очередь на интеллигенцию, коей сами и являются, а её представители болезнено относятся к слову "звОнит".

Comment: Марку: хоть это утешает.)

Comment: Кто-нибудь сможет сказать мне есть ли тут "личка", чтоб написать личное сообщение? И второй вопрос: Куда делся раздел "Исследования", кто знает? Или на худой конец как можно написать админу или модерам?

Comment: @НабиМусаибов приватной лички здесь нет, но если хотите отправить сообщение конкретному участнику, можно написать его ник и перед ним поставить @ как в этом комментарии. Исследования пропали при переезде на другой сайт. А ответы модераторов и администрации вы услышите, если зададите вопрос на Мете http://meta.rus.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Марк Из 
Спасибо огромное, уважаемый "Марк Из". 
Хочу внести предложения

1) Дать задание программистам организовать личку.  2) Восстановить "Исследования". Как считаете, какие есть преграды на этом пути?

Comment: @НабиМусаибов опубликуйте свои предложения на Мете и на ваши вопросы обязательно ответят. Здесь это оффтоп.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой В 1960-х года **на филологическом  факультете МГУ** среди студентов проводили исследование, и около 75% опрошенных говорили звОнит. Это потом, благодаря стараниям "радетелей за чистоту языка" стали болезненно относится к звОнит. Так что это всё искусственно. Про исследование отсюда: http://danefae.org/pprs/zlatou/orthoepia.htm Это выдержка из книги

Comment: Спасибо большое за ссылку, CITBL! Удивляет очень это, правда, насчёт 75 процентов!

Comment: @МаркИз
Спасибо огромное за совет. Но если честно я не знаю что такое "Мета", а стало быть не понял сказанное Вами.

Comment: @НабиМусаибов Русский язык Мета - это форум поддержки этого подфорума. Можно нажать на StackExchange сверху слева и увидеть Мету в списке.   http://meta.rus.stackexchange.com/